# Best way to generate seed data in a Rails app while preserving auto generated primary IDs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I'm working on a Rails 4 app. We have a `seed.rb` file that contains some fundamental data that our team works with, e.g.:

```
Country.delete_all
Country.create!(name: "United States", code: "US", description: "")
```

Every once in a while, we need to add more seed data to this file. But running `rake db:seed`, would first wipe the records in the referenced tables before inserting them back in again. Since the ID columns in these tables are auto generated, the old IDs would be lost. So, in someone's local development environment, lots of personal test data would be invalidated, because foreign keys are broken. Removing `.delete_all` from each model in seed.rb could pass as a solution, but running `db:seed` would output lots of errors.

So, I'm looking for a best practice in generating seed data while preserving the old primary keys (ID's in my case).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to remove them first you can use

> Country.where(name: "United States").first_or_create

This means that it will only be created if it doesn't already exist and so only the new seeds would be created, leaving the old records the same

Comment: If you want to add new values to it add them to the first or create

Country.where(name: "United States").first_or_create(code: "US", description: "")